# Trying to connect to aws s3 with boto3 by passing aws credentials as variables to airflow macros

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

I have one airflow connection that looks like this:

- Conn id : `my_conn_id`
- Conn type: `s3`
- Host: `my_host`
- Login: `abcd`

I tried to connect to my s3 using boto3 with the following code without luck

```
s3client = boto3.client(
        service_name='s3',
        region_name='us-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id="{{ conn.conn_id.host }}",
        aws_secret_access_key="{{ conn.conn_id.host }}"
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why have you supplied the same value for both access key and secret key?

Comment: I was just trying it out. Don't know what I should write for secret key. Airflow does not recognise `{{ conn.conn_id.host }}` I belive

Comment: I would not recommend guessing when [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html#authenticating-to-aws) is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection is misconfigured. Enter your aws_access_key_id as login and aws_secret_key_id as password. When you generated your AWS keys, you got both the access key and secret key - you will need them both. If you don't have the secret key, regenerate the keys in AWS. See connection details here - [Airflow AWS connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html)

In Airflow, you should use the S3Hook to generate a boto3 S3 client if you need to, but check out the functionality of the S3Hook first to see if you can use it to do your task. See functions here - [S3Hook source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_modules/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.html)

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
s3client = S3Hook(aws_conn_id=my_conn_id).get_conn()
```